# Why forbid "braced-init-list" in the built-in "operator[]"?

Tags: arrays, c++11, curly-braces, initializer-list

I just noticed, that in N3291 a change is marked (*5.2.1 Subscripting [expr.sub]*):

Before, it was ok to overload `operator[]` with the new *braced-init-list*:

```
struct X {
    Z operator[](std::initializer_list<int>);
};
X x;
x[{1,2,3}] = 7; // OK: meaning x.operator[]({1,2,3})
```

Now that is **removed and replaced** with:

> A braced-init-list shall not be used with the built-in subscript operator.

What was the problem?

Comment: My first reaction upon seeing `x[{1,2,3}]` was "Huh, what the...". Maybe that is the very reason. This basically creates an `operator[]` with an unusual syntax and _some unknown_ number of arguments (does it conceptually make sense for `operator[]` to take 1, or 2, or 3, or 755 indices?). And, it just puzzles you :P

Comment: No I just found it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3236.html#798 -- they just moved it because it was a strange place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x[{1,2,3}]` is not the built-in `[]` operator. It invokes a user defined operator function. So take a deep breath and go on using this fun syntax.

Comment: Nicely put. I only saw the red-marked strike-through section, got such a shock, that I probably did not take in the actual words *"built-in"*. Yes, And I *will* use it, I guess. For one, It probably be quite efficient (no copy, if programmed correctly), and second, it allows very mighty constructs. `valarray` does all this (and more) with "implicit" classes. This syntax does seem more straightforward to me.

Answer (score 2):

some careful googling pointed me to [issue 798](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3236.html#798), they only *moved* it to *13.5.5 [over.sub]*, not *deleted* it.